# Make container height following the items

Tags: flutter

So i have this structure

[image]

As you can see from the image, i have stack which has two childs `Container` & `SignalCardLabel` . In Container i set the height, but now i want to make it more dynamically. For now, here is my script

```
 Container(
        height: 117,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(8),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: //Expanded ),
```

I have try to remove the height but it throw this

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

Then i'm trying to wrap it with expanded, but still showing same result. Just in case you need my full script

Here is my `SignalCardLabel`

```
class SignalCardLabel extends StatelessWidget {
  Color chipColor;
  String signalActionType;
  SignalCardLabel({this.chipColor, this.signalActionType});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: chipColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.zero,
            topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.zero,
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 2, bottom: 2, right: 9),
          child: Text(
            signalActionType,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have `The following ParentDataWidgets are providing parent data to the same RenderObject` in the error message? if so what is below it?

Comment: hi @pskink , i did a mistake. Here is the error `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: You should use `Expanded` only within a `column`, `row` or `flex`.

Comment: hi @AashifAhamed , yes i already remove the `Expanded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Container` with `Positioned.fill`. It creates a Positioned object with left, top, right, and bottom set to 0.0 unless a value for them is passed.

You can not use `Expanded` there, it must be placed only inside Column, Row or Flex widgets.

Example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stack example',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Stack example'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 60,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item # $index'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPD:**
*When using a Stack you can't position children relative to their size or the stack's own size*
Remove `Positioned` there. Unless you will have third child in Stack, what you are trying to do will look like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stack example',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Stack example'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.zero,
                          topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                        ),
                      ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20, top: 2, bottom: 2, right: 9),
                        child: Text(
                          'This is an example',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, now it is throwing this `RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.`

Comment: Does your SignalCardLabel has finite size? This example works because Stack can take its size from second child.

Comment: @Boby when using a Stack you can't position children relative to their size or the stack's own size.

Comment: thank you, but the result is weird. Did i miss something ?, you can check my script here https://gist.github.com/bobykurniawan11/e008455a3eb8aef8d0da3c920cd61cd0 and here is the screnshoot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rcZ7vpHNq4dg0zQQVJwtXvLRbsc5PhN8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Boby does that has something to do with answer? You had error fixed, done. You had stack positioning rules explained, done. I am not supposed to rewrite all aligning of your code, this website is not about that. Imagine someone with same problem clicking on your question and finding out all we do here is modifying your code to make it look good.